# Executing functions and blocks through time

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit, hksamplequery

I don't understand how Objective-C loop system works. I have function (hope names are right, rather check in code) which executes query from Health Kit. I got my mind blown when I realised that function pass return value before query finishes.

```
__block bool allBeckuped = true;
HKSampleQuery *mySampleQuery = [[HKSampleQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:mySampleType
                                       predicate:myPredicate
                                           limit:HKObjectQueryNoLimit
                                 sortDescriptors:@[mySortDescriptor]
                                  resultsHandler:^(HKSampleQuery *query, NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                                      if(!error && results)
                                      {
                                          for(HKQuantitySample *samples in results)///main hk loop
                                          {
                                              allBeckuped = false;

                                              NSLog(@"1");
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }];//end of query

[healthStore executeQuery:mySampleQuery];
 NSLog(@"2");
return allBeckuped;
```

I'm trying to check if there are any new data, but I don't know where to put condition for that, because  nslog2 is called before nslog 1.

Any words I should Google up?

Comment: The query is done asynchronously in the background. That is why the return statement is reached long before the result handler is called.

Answer (score 0):

> Any words I should google up?

You can start with: asynchronous design, blocks, GCD/Grand Central Dispatch should help as well - you're not using it but asynchronous designs often do.

Look at the `initWithSampleType:` method you are calling, it is an example of a method following the asynchronous model. Rather than return a result immediately, which is the *synchronous* model you are probably used to, its last argument, `resultsHandler:`, is a block which the method calls *at some future time* passing the result of its operation to it.

This is the pattern you will need to learn and follow.

Your method which contains the call to `initWithSampleType:` cannot return a result (e.g. your `allBeckuped`) synchronously. So it needs to take a "results handler" block argument, and the block you pass to `initWithSampleType:` should call the block passed to your method - and so the asynchronous flow of control is weaved.

HTH

Comment: I see how it works... Thank you, you saved me a lot of time.